# Let Y and Z be homotopy equivalent subspaces of X, are their relative homology groups isomorphic?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I was wondering the following let $Y$ a subspace of  a space $X$ and suppose there exists another subspace $Z$ of $X$ such that  $Y$ and $Z$ are homotopy equivalent does it then follow that $H_n(X,Y) \cong H_n(X,Z)$ ?
Thanks

Comment: also will the relative homology groups be isomorphic when Y is a deformation retract of Z?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Note that homotopy equivalence sdoes not mean that we can defrom $Y$ into $Z$ inside $X$. Now see what happens if $Y$ is a suitable subspace of some $X_0$ and we let $X$ be the disjoint union of $X_0$ and $Z$ (which is a copy of $Y$). Then $H_n(X,Z)$ is given by cyles in $X$ with boundary in $Y$ in the $X_0$ component and boundaryless cycles in the $Z$ component; whereas $H_n(X,Z)$ is given by boundaryless cycles in $X_0$ and arbitrary cycles in the $Z$ component.  I suppose you can easily find examples of $Y$ and $X_0$ that make these homologies differ.

Answer (score 2):

No. Consider the example where X is a wedge of a circle and a 2-disk, and Y and Z are the circle and the boundary of the disk.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine if that were the case. Then H(X,A) would only tell you about the spaces X and A, and nothing at all about how they're related. It wouldn't be a very useful functor!