# Let Y and Z subspaces of X such that Y deformation retarcts to Z are their relative homology groups isomorphic?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I was wondering the following let $Y$ a subspace of a space $X$ and suppose there exists another subspace $Z$ of $X$ such that $Y$ deformation retracts to $Z$ does it then follow that
$H_n(X,Y)≅H_n(X,Z)$
Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't [SPM's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1283529/10014) to your last question still a counterexample...? A point does deformation retract onto a point.

Comment: yeah i guess it is... I am confused now because pedro answer seems correct as well

Comment: so i guess the groups are isomorphic if the Z lies inside Y i.e it dosent work in the cases like SPM's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the exact sequence of the pair for $(Y, Z)$ we have $... \rightarrow H_n(Z) \rightarrow H_n(Y) \rightarrow H_n(Y, Z) \rightarrow H_{n - 1}(Z) \rightarrow H_{n - 1}(Y) \rightarrow ...$. The map $H_n(Z) \rightarrow H_n(Y)$ is induced by the inclusion which is a homotopy equivalence (since $Y$ deformation retracts to $Z$), hence it is an isomorphism, and similarly for the map $H_{n-1}(Z) \rightarrow H_{n-1}(Y)$. Using this information and the exactness of the sequence it is easy to see that $H_n(Y, Z) = 0$.

Then we look at the exact sequence of the triple $... \rightarrow H_n(Y, Z) \rightarrow H_n(X, Z) \rightarrow H_n(X, Y) \rightarrow H_{n-1}(Y, Z) \rightarrow ...$, but since the homology groups of $(Y, Z)$ are zero we get the isomorphism $H_n(X, Z) \cong H_n(X, Y)$.